# Convert columns to rows in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

May I know how I can output result from this query to this format?

Query is

```
Select * 
from sys.databases 
where name = 'your_db_name'
```

Original output:

```
name  databaseid  source_database_id  owner_sid
xxx   xxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxx
```

Desired output:

```
Parameter           Value
name                xxxxx
databaseid          xxxxx
source_database_id  xxxxxx
owner_sid           xxxxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Cross Apply` and `Table valued constructor` to unpivot the data

```
SELECT Parameter,
       Value
FROM   yourtable
       CROSS apply (VALUES ('name',name),
                           ('databaseid',Cast(databaseid AS VARCHAR(100))),
                           ('source_database_id',Cast(source_database_id AS VARCHAR(100))),
                           ('owner_sid',Cast(owner_sid AS VARCHAR(100))))cs(Parameter, Value)
```

**Note:** You may have employ dynamic code if no. of columns are unknown

Comment: You might want to `CAST` the `Value` to `VARCHAR`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan - Yep, didnt check the name column